# How do I symlink files as a batch?

Tags: bash

I have a folder of files `folderA/` and an empty folder `folderB/`

```
folderA/
    file1
    file2
    file3
    ...

folderB/
```

How can I create a symlink in `folderB/` to each file in `folderA/` without linking each individually?  There are lots of files.  Using bash, Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried the answer given here: https://superuser.com/a/429508 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347142/6673905, but it did not work.

From `folderA/`, I ran

```
ln -s * /path/to/folderB/
```

It created symlink cycles in `folderB/`:

```
folderB/
    file1 -> file1
    file2 -> file2
    file3 -> file3
    ...
```

where the symlinks link *to themselves*, not to files in `folderA/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s * /path/to/folderB/
```

Is equivalent to use:

```
ln -s file1 file2 file3 /path/to/folderB/
```

In my experience, ln -s is very picky about the paths.

You can try:

```
ln -s $PWD/* /path/to/folderB/
```